# flutter js-interop streamcontroller not updating value from listprovider

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I want to send a UInt8list(3) from flutter to the js-side to use the data with WebMidi.
Starting from the element_embedding example i added some riverpod providers for the data.

```
    final listProvider3 = StateProvider<Uint8List>((_) {
           return Uint8List.fromList([144, 68, 70]); });  //Npte-on event
```

I have a table of 8*16 buttons and a listprovider for their states:

```
final listProvider1 = StateProvider<List<int>>((_) {
  return List.generate(8 * 16, (_) => 0);
});
```

another listprovider to hold the current stepnumber for each row of buttons:

```
 final steplistProvider = StateProvider<List<int>>((_) {
  return List.generate(8, (_) => 0);
```

I use a countdowntimer to update the steplistprovider every 250ms.
In the build method of _MyAppState I listen to steplistprovider:

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ref.listen(steplistProvider, (previous, next) {
      final steps = ref.read(steplistProvider);
      final list1 = ref.read(listProvider1);
      final Uint8List listBytes = ref.read(listProvider3);
     
       for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (list1[steps[i] + i * 16] > 0) {  //Button selected?
                     
          listBytes[0] = 144;
          listBytes[1] = 30 + i;  //Here i increment the value
          listBytes[2] = 70;
          ref.read(listProvider3.notifier).state = listBytes;
         
          sendToJs();  //call function in loop
          }}}

 @js.JSExport()
  void sendToJs() 
{
         setState(() {
    
      final listBytes = ref.read(listProvider3);
      byteList = listBytes;
      _streamController.add(null);
    }
  }
```

From the loop I call sendToJs and add my bytelist to a _streamcontroller.
on the Js-side there is a callback when the streamcontroller emits:
demo-js-interop.js

```
  let updateState = function () {
      valueField.value = appState.mybuffer;  //the Uint8list from flutter
      myFunction(appState.mybuffer);
     };

    // Register a callback to update the HTML field from Flutter.
    appState.addHandler(updateState);
```

myFunction(appState.mybuffer); is a js-function where data is sent via WebMidi
In class _MyAppState I have:

```
var byteList = Uint8List(3);
@js.JSExport()
  void addHandler(void Function() handler) {
    _streamController.stream.listen((event) {
      handler();
    });
  }

  @js.JSExport()
  Uint8List get mybuffer => byteList;
```

Expected behaviour: Every 250 ms the steplistprovider is updated and in a loop in ref.listen(steplistprovider) i call the sendToJs function. In my Matrix of buttons if i select two buttons in the same column(step) i want to send out two diffrent Uint8List.

But with the Code above it sends out the same value twice. I think it's the streamcontroller sending the latest value twice.
If button 1 and button 8 are selected I would expect listBytes[1] to be  30 and 37 but it sends 37 two times.
It does send two events but with the same (higher) value.
the bug must be in the loop and the way _streamcontroller is used.

This really blocks me from continuing with my app.

Answer (score 1):

I had to set sync field in streamcontroller.

```
final _streamController = StreamController<void>.broadcast(sync: true);
```